# How to identify public and private subnet in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have joined project. Subnets are not properly named. So how to identify public and private subnet in vpc?

How can route table help me? Can someone please check?

Answer (score 4):

To identify whether a subnet is a Public Subnet:

- In the VPC management console, click on the subnet
- Click on the **Route table** tab

If there is an entry with a **Destination** of `0.0.0.0/0` that points to `igw-xxxx`, then it is sending traffic for the internet through an Internet Gateway. This makes it a **Public Subnet**.

For example:

[image: VPC Subnet Route Table]

Answer (score 0):

Public subnets are those that have a route to the internet gateway. Private ones are those which don't have such a route.